# dynamic colored polygons in leaflet shiny r

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am attempting to create an r shiny leaflet app that can dynamically color shade polygons with a pal spectrum depending on user input.  Note I am not just coloring the polygons, I also want to use a color range to illustrate a range of values across a variable. (Hence the need for the pal spectrum)

The code below works fine - but the pal and fillColor inputs are not dynamic here.

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
map <- readShapeSpatial(paste(input$state,"Zip.shp",sep=""))

pal <- colorNumeric(
 palette = "YlGnBu",
 domain = map$college)

leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
addPolygons(data=map,
         fillColor=~pal(college),
fillOpacity = 0.7, 
 weight = 1, 
smoothFactor = 0.2)
 })}
```

But the version below fails.  It creates a "no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector" Error.   Why does this error occur and how can I fix this problem?

Code that fails:

```
 output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

 map <- readShapeSpatial(paste(input$state,"Zip.shp",sep=""))

 pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "YlGnBu",
  domain = paste(map,"input$fill",sep=""))

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(data=map,
              fillColor=~pal(input$fill),
              fillOpacity = 0.7, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2)
```

Why can't I use the dynamic shiny input of input$fill to set the pal spectrum and fillColor for the Polygons?  Any possible work arounds?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should at least show us what is `input$fill`

Comment: input$fill are different variable names such as "college","income","population" that refer to data sets that have been co-joined with shapefile maps via the geo_join function in r using the tigris package.

Comment: Note the parent map object is a ShapeSatial file - but the class of the options for input$fill such as map$college, map$population and so on are integers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your case can be solved by [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954132). Hence you should use `fillColor = ~pal()(input$fill)`.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21896502)

Comment: OK. Edited answer accordingly.